# How to remove characters after new line and space between words

Tags: python, regex

I have list below

`a = ['\ntest_ dev\n$', 'pro gra', 'test\n', 'test\n']`

- I need to remove `space` from in between elements and strip out after the `\n`
- I need to remove duplicate from the list

expected out is `['test_dev', 'progra', 'test']`

Code is below

```
def remove_tags(text):
    tag_re = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
    remove_tag = tag_re.sub('', text)
    return remove_tag.replace(" ", "")
def remove_tags_newline(text):
    tag_re = re.compile(r'\n')
    remove_tag = tag_re.sub('', text)
    return remove_tag.replace(" ", "")
l = []
for i in a:
    s = remove_tags_newline(remove_tags(i))
    if s not in l:
        l.append(s)
l
```

My out is `['\\ntest_dev\\n$', 'progra', 'test']`
expected out is `['test_dev', 'progra', 'test']`

Comment: There are no newlines in `'\\ntest_ dev\\n$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you solve for `\ntest_ dev\n$`

Comment: Try `def remove_tags_newline(text): return "".join(re.sub('(?s)\n.*', '', text.strip()).split())` if you have ``a = ['\ntest_ dev\n$', 'pro gra', 'test\n', 'test\n']``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you only have line feed chars in the input, not combinations of backslash and `n`.

In this case, you can fix your code by using

```py
def remove_tags_newline(text):
    return "".join(re.sub('(?s)\n.*', '', text.strip()).split())
```

It does the following:

- `re.sub('(?s)\n.*', '', text.strip())` - removes any leading/trailing whitespace chars and then removes any text after the first line feed char including it (note that `(?s)` is a `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` equivalent inline modifier that lets `.` match across lines, and `\n` matches LF chars and `.*` matches any zero or more chars as many as possible)
- `.split()` - splits the string with whitespace
- `"".join(...)` - concats all the strings from the list into a single string without adding any delimiters between the items (thus, removes any whitespace together with `.split()`).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xjLUe9):

```py
import re
a = ['\ntest_ dev\n$', 'pro gra', 'test\n', 'test\n']
def remove_tags_newline(text):
    return "".join(re.sub('(?s)\n.*', '', text.strip()).split())
print( [remove_tags_newline(x) for x in a] )
# => ['test_dev', 'progra', 'test', 'test']
```

Comment: @sim I do not understand that question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68033881/how-to-add-the-characters-between-the-strings-with-conditions

Comment: i have update the new question, can you check once