# How to add the characters between the strings with conditions

Tags: python, regex

- if %20 there in the string it has to replace with OR, abc %20 def. Expected out -- > `'*abc* OR *def*'`
- if , there in the string it has to replace with OR, abc,def.: Expected out -- > `'*abc* OR *def*'`
- string = 'abc def': Need to update beginning each string and end string with * replace space with OR.:  Expected out --> `'*abc* OR *def*'`
- string = 'abc or def', 'abc+def','abc + def', 'abc OR def': If OR,+ is in the string then we need to update.:  Expected out --> `'*abc* OR *def*'`
- string = 'abc&def','abc & def', 'abc and def' abc AND def': If AND,& is in the string then we need to update.: Expected out --> `'*abc* AND *def*'`
- string = 'abc', : Expected out --> `'*abc*`
- string = 'abc  def  ghi':  Expected out --> `'*abc* OR *def* OR *ghi*'`
- All the punctuations has to replace

Code is below

```
import re
def format_search_value(search_value_1):
    punctuations = '''!()[]{};:"\,<>./?@#%^*~'''
    search_value_1 = search_value_1.replace('+', ' ')
    #if %20 there in the string it has to replace with OR, abc %20 def
    search_value_1 = re.sub('^(%20)+$', '%20', search_value_1)
    search_value = ""
    for char in search_value_1:
        if char not in punctuations:
            search_value = search_value + char
    search_expression = ','.join([f'*{word.strip()}*' for word in search_value.split(',')])
    search_expression = re.sub(' +', ' ', search_expression.replace('%20', ' '))
    search_expression = ','.join([f'*{word}*' for word in search_expression.split(' ')])
    search_parameter = search_expression.replace('%20', ' OR ').replace(',', ' OR ') \
        .replace('and', 'AND').replace('+', 'OR').replace('or', 'OR').strip()
    search_parameter = search_parameter.replace('**', '*')
    return search_parameter
format_search_value('abc or def')
```

I am getting proper output only for ('abc def') which is `'*abc* OR *def*'`

Comment: have updated the expected out, stack overflow could not find * in the word,, so i have explicitly add ` in the expected out, sorry for inconvenience caused

Comment: How do you want to replace all the punctuations except for + sign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the awesome answers given by Kraigolas and Will, I tried a different approach which requires only one regex.

Input (stolen from Will's answer :D)

```py
import re

test_cases = (
    'abc %20 def',
    'abc %20 def',
    'abc or def',
    'abc OR def',
    'abc+def',
    'abc + def',
    'abc&def',
    'abc & def',
    'abc AND def',
    'abc and def',
)
```

Pattern capturing 5 groups as described below.

`group1`: `(\w+)\s?` Captures all letters before first space

`group2`: `((or|OR|\+|%20)|(&|and|AND))` Wrapping group for group 3 and 4 (This is what make it possible to create one regex)

`group3`: `(or|OR|\+|%20)` Captures `or`, `OR`, `+`, `%20`

`group4`: `(&|and|AND)` Captures `&`, `and`, `AND`

`group5`: `\s?(\w+)` Captures all letters after the last space.

Note that `\s?` captures one or 0 spaces.

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s?((or|OR|\+|%20)|(&|and|AND))\s?(\w+)')
```

Format the strings as follow. If group 3 exits then replace with `OR`. Else replace with `AND`. (Note that when group 3 is null, group 4 is non-null and vice versa.)

```py
def format_value(text):
    match = pattern.match(text)
    if match is not None and match.group(3):
        return pattern.sub(r'*\1* OR *\5*', text)
    else:
        return pattern.sub(r'*\1* AND *\5*', text)
```

```py
for x in test_cases:
    print(format_value(x))
```

Output

```
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
```

**EDIT**
To capture `abc def ghi` here is a small hack.

Create another pattern to capture the spaces. This will not capture already formatted strings with * on both sides as I'm searching for a space surrounded by 2 word characters.

```py
space_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w)(\s)(\w)')
```

Update format value method by removing leading and trailing asterisk.

```py
def format_value(text):
    match = pattern.match(text)
    if match is not None and match.group(3):
        return pattern.sub(r'\1* OR *\5', text)
    else:
        return pattern.sub(r'\1* AND *\5', text)
```

Reformat the string as follow and add trailing and leading asterisk back.

```py
for x in test_cases:
    formatted_value = format_value(x)
    print("*" + space_pattern.sub(r'\1* OR *\3', formatted_value) + "*")
```

Output

```
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc*
*abc* OR *def* OR *ghi*
```

Comment: can you help to achieve one more scenario

Comment: if i am passing single string or more than double string its not working, single = 'abc', : Expected out --> 'abc, more than double = 'abc def ghi': Expected out --> 'abc OR def OR ghi'

Comment: @sim I have added an edit to my post. Please check if this solved your problem completely.

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

This answer was created before the question was updated to show that the expected output needed to surround `abc` and `def` with `\*`'s. Feel free to borrow from it to create a more relevant answer to the new question.

### Original Answer

This can actually be done in a couple lines. Here, I'll just substitute all matches (not just one occurrence):

```
import re

text = """
abc %20 def
abc %20 def
abc or def
abc+def
abc + def

abc&def
abc & def
abc AND def
"""

or_pattern = re.compile("\s*(%20|\+)\s*|\s+or\s+")
text = or_pattern.sub(" OR ", text)

and_pattern = re.compile("\s*&\s*|\s+AND\s+")
text = and_pattern.sub(" AND ", text)
```

The output for `text` is now:

```
abc OR def
abc OR def
abc OR def
abc OR def
abc OR def

abc AND def
abc AND def
abc AND def
```

### or pattern

```
\s*(%20|\+)\s*|\s+or\s+
```

This is split into two parts separated by a regex "or" `|`:

```
\s*(%20|\+)\s*
```

- `\s*` says match 0 or more spaces (to be restrictive, you could say `s{0,1}` to capture 0 or 1 spaces only)
- `(%20|\+)` says match (and capture, which is necessary for the regex `|`'s, which mean "or") any one of `%20`, or `+` between the two `\s*`

and

```
\s+or\s+
```

This part is separated because we need at least one space on each side of the `or`, otherwise `door` would be replaced with `do OR` .

### Case insensitivity

In your case, you might also want `oR` and `Or` to match, in which case you can use `re.compile("pattern", re.IGNORECASE)`.

Comment: I have updated the expected out, stack overflow could not find * in the word,

Comment: so i have explicitly add ` in the expected out, sorry for inconvenience caused

Answer (score 2):

Working off of what Kraigolas provided, here is a solution to your problem:

```
import re

or_pattern = re.compile(r'\s*(%20|\+)\s*|\s+or\s+', re.IGNORECASE)
and_pattern = re.compile(r'\s*&\s*|\s+and\s+', re.IGNORECASE)
operand_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*(OR|AND)\s*(\w+)')

def format_search_value(search_value):
    search_value = or_pattern.sub(' OR ', search_value)
    search_value = and_pattern.sub(' AND ', search_value)
    return operand_pattern.sub(r'*\1* \2 *\3*', search_value)
```

It does all of what Kraigolas' answer does, and then additionally uses the `operand_pattern` to surround the operands with asterisks. It uses 3 capture groups in the pattern:

1. The first operand: `(\w+)`
2. The operator: `(OR|AND)`
3. The second operand: `(\w+)`
   These three captured values are then inserted into the substitution string with the asterisks using the special values `\1`, `\2`, and `\3`: `*\1* \2 *\3*`

Usage:

```
test_cases = (
    'abc %20 def',
    'abc %20 def',
    'abc or def',
    'abc OR def',
    'abc+def',
    'abc + def',
    'abc&def',
    'abc & def',
    'abc AND def',
    'abc and def',
)

for search_value in test_cases:
    print(format_search_value(search_value))
```

Output:

```
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* OR *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
*abc* AND *def*
```

Comment: can you check the output?? I got `abc OR def` there is no * between

Comment: can you check your code, i think you forgot to copy paste

Comment: can you help to achieve one more scenario

Comment: if i am passing single string or more than double string its not working,
single =  'abc', : Expected out --> '*abc*,   more than double = 
'abc def ghi': Expected out --> '*abc* OR *def* OR *ghi*'

Comment: @sim If you have additional questions, you should ask additional questions, not update the same one.